Stationary distribution of periodic Markov chain
Let $P$ an irreducible stochastic matrix with finite state space $E$. Then $P$ has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$. If $P$ is aperiodic, then the convergence theorem tells us something about the interpretation of this distribution. But what if $P$ is not necessarely aperiodic? Do we have a generic result? Here is my guess: Suppose that I start the chain in $x_0\in E$ and I measure $n$ times to obtain a list $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n$. My guess would be that if $n$ is large enough, then
$$\forall x\in E:\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}(x_i)\approx \pi(x).$$
Is my intuition correct and are there any rigorous results (e.g. convergence in probability)?

Yes, it is a standard result that the fraction of time being in state $i$ converges to $\pi_i$ with probability 1, regardless of the initial state. Renewal theory can be used to prove this.

The result is known as "ergodic theorem". See e.g. sections 1.10 and 3.8 in Norris' Markov chains for discrete-time and continuous-time, respectively.
